# What would be an ideal measure for the synchrony of laughter?

Tags: time-series, correlation, psychology

I am exploring the relationship between the quality of connection two people share and the tendency for their laughter to synchronize. In order to do this, I need some way to quantify the degree of synchrony. The measure that has seemed most promising to me so far is "r" (order) from Kuramoto's model. My understanding is that in using this measure, I am making the assumption that the laughter oscillations are described by a sinusoidal function.

My actual data is a series of points, each representing the time at which the amplitude of a laugh-call peaks, so I am wondering if this is an ideal representation.

Comment: "Ideal" in what sense? This sounds a bit like a substantive, scientific judgment, & I don't know if anyone here will know the pros & cons of different ways of thinking about the synchrony of laughter. If you are looking for a *statistical* ideal, we may be of more help, but could you describe the issue more fully? What is "Kuramoto's model"? Are you just trying to determine how well synchronized 2 sine waves are with respect to their frequency, amplitude, periods, or some combination?

Comment: The focus seems misplaced. The question is if two people are closer, do they tend to laugh at a closer temporal proximity. You have their voice file, and so you should have their time elapsed between peaks. Then you'll just need their closeness variable. Check their association and your question answered. Why bother with defining synchrony using sin function? Laughter isn't even an oscillatory event; I fail to see how sin function can help here. And of course, how to define "quality of connection" is another topic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could show us a plot of this time series?

Name the two persons A, B.  Find points which correspond to the same "laugh call" maybe based on some maximum time difference. How many laugh calls have both A and B? How many only one of them? That would be informative. Also, for the laugh calls with both A,B, is always A first? always B first? or do they alternate in some way? What is the typical time difference? Is it the same when A first as with B first?

Maybe some results could come from such descriptions. Can you show us some such descriptive stats, then maybe we can have better ideas?